# Ruby find out what mode file is opened in

Tags: ruby

I need to check what method a file object is opened in. E.g. is it r, r+, w, a etc.

```
thefile = File.open(filename, method)
```

It must be using the object thefile and not just the filename.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 6):

On POSIX platforms, you can call [`IO#fcntl`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-fcntl) with F_GETFL to get the file status flags:

```
require 'fcntl'

def filemode(io)
  flags = io.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL)
  case flags & Fcntl::O_ACCMODE
  when Fcntl::O_RDONLY
    'r'
  when Fcntl::O_WRONLY
    (flags & Fcntl::O_APPEND).zero? ? 'w' : 'a'
  when Fcntl::O_RDWR
    (flags & Fcntl::O_APPEND).zero? ? 'r+ / w+' : 'a+'
  end
end

File.open('test.txt', 'r') { |f| puts filemode(f) }   #=> r
File.open('test.txt', 'w') { |f| puts filemode(f) }   #=> w
File.open('test.txt', 'a+') { |f| puts filemode(f) }  #=> a+
```

`fcntl`'s return value is a bitwise OR of the individual `O_*` flags:

```
Fcntl::O_RDONLY   # 0
Fcntl::O_WRONLY   # 1
Fcntl::O_RDWR     # 2
Fcntl::O_APPEND   # 4
Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK # 8
```

`Fcntl::O_ACCMODE` can be used to mask the file access modes.

Further information:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Status-Flags.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fcntl/rdoc/Fcntl.html

Comment: Although this is the right way... this isn't working for me. It always passes through to `nil`.  Does `case` work that way? Those values are effectively integers so it's like saying. `case 1231321 when 1 when 2 `. Where is the bitwise AND implied?

Comment: Also, this is only for POSIX platforms.

Comment: @Stefan nice! You could differentiate between `r+` and `w+` with something like `O_TRUNC` too.  `if flags | Fcntl::O_TRUNC | Fcntl::O_APPEND == flags then 'w+' elsif flags | Fcntl::O_APPEND == flags then 'a+' else 'r+' end`

Comment: @Matt does that work on your system? The `O_TRUNC` flag is never set on my system.

Comment: It did on cygwin but you're right, not on others.  I think that's the first time I've ever seen cygwin do something useful over normal Ruby!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the full script for you, but will give you a hint.

Suppose you have an IO opened:

```
io = File.open("/tmp/foo", "r")
```

Assuming that `io` was created successfully, you can tell whether it is opened for writing by attempting `write`:

```
begin
  io.write("")
rescue IOError => e
  puts e.message
end
#=> not opened for writing
```

Make sure to copy the file before attempting this in order not to lose the file in case the mode was `"w"` or `"w+"`.

Do along the same line for distinguishing other modes.

Comment: How do you propose to copy the file when all you have is the `IO` object and you don't know if it is readable or even seekable?